# How to change this json object to json array to consume it with Volley?

Tags: android, json, gson, android-volley

I am trying to consume below record using JSON with `Volley`, but it is not a JSONArray, How can I change it to use it in :

```
JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
```

Mean while, The URL in the record seems not correct. How to remove extar forward slashes from url or I can use it to fetch the JPG image?

```
{
    "ID": "131",
    "Lead": "",
    "Title": "\u06f2\u06f0 \u06af\u0644 \u0641\u0648\u0642      \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0627\u062f\u0647 \u0631\u0648\u0646\u0627\u0644\u062f\u0648 \u062f\u0631 \u0644\u06cc\u06af \u0642\u0647\u0631\u0645\u0627\u0646\u0627\u0646",
    "ContentTime": "09:56",
    "TypeContent": "public",
    "PTime": "1395\/05\/09 - 11:47",
    "Content": " <\/div>",
    "Tags": "\u0641\u0648\u062a\u0628\u0627\u0644#\u0631\u0648\u0646\u0627\u0644\u062f\u0648#\u0648\u0631\u0632\u0634\u06cc#######",
    "Price": "0",
    "GID": "106",
    "GTitle": "\u0648\u0631\u0632\u0634\u06cc",
    "PicURL": "http:\/\/video.dmedia.ir\/images\/news\/131\/thumb_131.jpg",
    "comment_count": "0",
    "view_count": "0",
    "Media": [{
        "GID": "359",
        "GType": "mp4",
        "Title": "",
        "URL": "http:\/\/video.dmedia.ir\/images\/news\/131\/media\/359.mp4",
        "ADV": 0
    }],
    "smscontent": null,
    "Rels": [{
        "RelID": "130",
        "RelTitle": " \u0645\u0647\u062f\u0648\u06cc: \u062f\u0648\u0633\u062a \u062f\u0627\u0631\u0645 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u0644\u0645 \u0628\u0627 \u06cc\u06a9 \u062e\u0627\u0637\u0631\u0647 \u062e\u0648\u0628 \u062a\u0645\u0648\u0645 \u0634\u0648\u062f"
    }],
    "Comments": []
}
```

Solution:

We can make JSON object request and JSON array request:
I found this helpful.
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/

Comment: What is your issue? The `JSON` seems fine.

Comment: I want to get this json object with Volley "JsonArrayRequest", and I think I have to give Volley, jsonarray not jsonobject.

Comment: Why cant you use `JsonObjectRequest`?

Answer (score 1):

hi there is one plugin **Gson** for android studio.You need to install.Then go to CTRL + insert. 
You can create gson file.
Enter some name for java file.

Click that file then Paste you json data. Click ok.
You can see your created json to gson format.

thanks hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

create model class for this data then use follwing code 
 ModelClass class=new GSON.fromJSON("your Data ", ModelClass.class )